# How is Android binder handle generated？

Tags: android, android-binder

When app need use functions provided by Android system server service, app will getService from ServiceManager first, then call API to send data to system service. When send data to system service by binder driver, there is a call writeStrongBinder(). By reading code of writeStrongBinder, I get to know that finally a binder handle value will be wrote to the binder data stream.

My question is, how is binder handle generated? Is there a global binder handle management mechanism? If binder handle is generated by each process separately, handle value may conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parcel.writeStrongBinder will call flatten_binder. From code of flatten_binder, we know that when "IBinder *local = binder->localBinder();" is not NULL, memory address will be used to transfer Binder between different process.

```
status_t flatten_binder(const sp<ProcessState>& proc,
    const sp<IBinder>& binder, Parcel* out)
{
    flat_binder_object obj;
    
    obj.flags = 0x7f | FLAT_BINDER_FLAG_ACCEPTS_FDS;
    if (binder != NULL) {
        IBinder *local = binder->localBinder();
        if (!local) {
            BpBinder *proxy = binder->remoteBinder();
            if (proxy == NULL) {
                ALOGE("null proxy");
            }
            const int32_t handle = proxy ? proxy->handle() : 0;
            obj.type = BINDER_TYPE_HANDLE;
            obj.handle = handle;
            obj.cookie = NULL;
        } else {
            obj.type = BINDER_TYPE_BINDER;
            obj.binder = local->getWeakRefs();
            obj.cookie = local;
        }
    } else {
        obj.type = BINDER_TYPE_BINDER;
        obj.binder = NULL;
        obj.cookie = NULL;
    }
    
    return finish_flatten_binder(binder, obj, out);
}
```

For binder server implementation, they are descendants of BBinder. BBinder return memory address of itself as localBinder()

```
BBinder* BBinder::localBinder()
{
    return this;
}
```

So conclusion: memory address is used as binder handle. There is no mechanism of binder handle generation and maintenance logic.

Answer (score 0):

The BpBinder Handler comes from  flat_binder_object  handle field, and then that handle value comes from kernel binder_ref.data.decs field . That just a integer noly 。The binder diver can use this handle to find real binder_node，and then target proc info。